# Tally Marks in Japanese?

Tags: orthography

In English, if we're tallying something on a piece of paper, etc., we usually write a vertical line to count 1, and then when you reach four of them, you cross it with a horizontal line to mean 5, and repeat. I saw a Japanese paper that seemed to be a similar concept, but the kanji 一 seemed to be used for 1, and the kanji 正 seemed to be used for 5 (there weren't any other numbers shown). What's the whole system in Japanese?

Comment: As a small remark, in case you are looking for the characters in your fonts... The five tally marks are not yet available in Unicode (of course similar characters can be used *in lieu* of them, though it is not the preferred way), but they are slated for the summer 2017, Unicode 10 release: [latest proposal](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2016/16046-ideo-tally-marks.pdf). Among other things slated to come this summer (2017) are hentaigana and further small kana forms.

Comment: Ooh, that's interesting. Unicode is always fun.

Comment: ***Correction:*** I got the numbers wrong, sorry about that! While Hentaigana *is* coming this summer (along with further kanji, some Chinese luck symbols and a slew of emoji among other additions), we have to wait some more for the tally marks and small kana forms, till summer **2018**, I guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The conventional Japanese tally follows the stroke order for 正. So if the total were 8, it'd look like [正下], and if it were 20, it'd be [正正正正]

This link shows an animation for the stroke order:
http://kakijun.jp/page/sei200.html

Comment: Ah, so 一 wasn't "one," it was the first stroke of 正. Thanks for the clarification.